# PHP Multidimensional Array Merge based on keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

i have this two arrays:

```
$array1 = [
  '1' => 285.52,
  '2' => 427.76
];

$array2 = [
  '1' => 123.44,
  '2' => 48.32
];
```

The keys on each of them are the id for the client, the first one is the amount owed and the second one is the amount payed, i want to achieve the following:

```
$mergedArrays = [
   '1' => [
     'owed'  => 285.52,
     'payed' => 123.44
   ],
   '2' => [
     'owed'  => 427.76,
     'payed' => 48.32
   ]
];
```

I was wondering if there's a PHP function to do so, i tried with array_merge_recursive but it just makes an array with the four elements together.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: whats the problem in traditional looping ?

Comment: Nothing built in without nesting/chaining a few built in functions like [array_column](http://php.net/array_column) with [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine) and similar.

Comment: @HillaryClintonEmailRemover I dunno, i thought it was more efficient performance wise to do it using built in functions, thanks tho

Answer (score 1):

you can loop in the first array and merge the second according to keys

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
    $mergedArrays[$key] = array('owed' => $val, 'payed' => $array2[$key]);
}
```

[sample](http://ideone.com/B4wIZ2)

Comment: he said non traditional

Comment: There's nothing not traditional as built in function for this

Comment: exectly what i thought i dunno why he wants to use some complex things to do simple tasks

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = [
  '1' => 285.52,
  '2' => 427.76
];

$array2 = [
  '1' => 123.44,
  '2' => 48.32
];

$final_arr = array_map(function($a1, $a2) {
    return array(
        'owed' => $a1,
        'paid' => $a2
    );
}, $array1, $array2);

$final_arr = array_combine(array_keys($array1), $final_arr);

var_dump($final_arr);
```

Based on the comment, it seems you're looking for built-in PHP functions to do the task for you rather than going for traditional looping. But the looping method provided by **Fabio** is the simplest one you could go for without any other complicated approaches. I've tried my best to provide you the solution using the core PHP functions. Hope you're happy with it!